# Exclude URL Array from jQuery .load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following script to load pages on Wordpress.

I am trying to exclude an array of url addresses from being load via the jquery page load in the scrippt. I  was thinking of using an if statement using the targetPage variable but am having trouble making array the of exclusions.

The Urls' are in the format of:

**/special-offers/**

**/contact/**

```
  jQuery('ul.menu li a').click(function() {
      jQuery('section').fadeOut(500);
          var targetPage = jQuery(this).attr('href');
              targetPage += " section";
      setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery('section').load(targetPage, function() {
              jQuery('section').fadeIn(500);
          });
      });
  return false;
  });
```

So basically if var targetPage does not = array of {/special-offers/,/contact/} then .load does not fire

Comment: Your question is unclear (where and what do you want to exclude), your setTimeout misses an argument, your targetPage seems to be bad formatted...

Comment: ok so if targetPage does not equal url's ending with:

'{
/special-offers/
/contact/
}'

Comment: so the load will not fire if the url ends in `/special-offers/, /contact/, ...`?

Comment: yes that is it exactly

Comment: You can use '$.inArray(value, array)' and parse your href to check if the value is in your array of excluded values (be carefull, $.inArray doesn't return a boolean, but an index).

Comment: any chance of example code?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the following way:

declare the excluded url endings in an array (no slashes)

```
var excludedURLs = ['special-offers', 'contact'];
```

Then in the timeout function you can check if the url ending is in the `excludedURLs` array:

```
jQuery('ul.menu li a').click(function () {
    var excludedURLs = ['special-offers', 'contact'];

    jQuery('section').fadeOut(500);

    var targetPage = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    targetPage += " section";

    setTimeout(function () {
        var lastSegment = targetPage.split('/');
        var result = lastSegment[lastSegment.length - 2];
        if (!jQuery.inArray(result, excludedURLs) > -1) {
            jQuery('section').load(targetPage, function () {
                jQuery('section').fadeIn(500);
            });
        }
    },250);
    return false;
});
```

An example of the `targetPage` would be `http://example.com/abcd/contact/`

Comment: still seems to be firing load

Comment: make sure that the `excludedUrls` have no `/` in them. it wont work if they have `/`